# Apply same operation to every byte in array

Tags: vhdl

I have a large array of 2 bits elements. I access these elements one after another at every clock cycle changing the value of the 2 bits depending on the inputs of my design.
Now, after having accessed them all, I would like to set at a certain value (let's say, 11) all the cells that currently contain a specific value (like 10). I need to do it in one clock cycle.

My first idea was to design a single register with a multiplexer at its input, so I can decide which value give to the register, but it does not seems the smartest idea to me (because I need to instantiate N times this new component, and I do not know if it will be easy to access sequentially all these components).

Is there a smart and simple way to do that? I guess that maybe the solution could be using the keyword OTHERS, but I found no clues about how to use that, even in the  VHDL reference manual.

EDIT: this was the component I had in mind.

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.all;

entity cell is
  port (
    reset, clk, set, calc: in std_logic;
    data: out std_logic_vector
  );
end entity;

architecture arch of cell is

signal my_reg: std_logic_vector(1 downto 0);

begin

    data <= my_reg;

    main : process(clk, reset)
    begin
        if(reset = '0') then
            my_reg <= "00";
        elsif(clk'event and clk = '0') then
            if(set = '1') then
                my_reg <= "01";
            elsif(calc = '1' and my_reg = "01") then
                my_reg <= "11";
            else
                my_reg <= "00";
            end if;
        end if;
    end process;

end architecture;
```

Even instantiating it many times, I do not know how to access in sequence every 'set' signal and globally all the 'calc' signals.

Comment: Trust you first idea, think nested generate statements.  If you're going to ask vague questions you'll get vague answers at best. Show us one of these two bit 'cell' components and describe the interconnections to/from wherever else in terms of array type elements.

Comment: @DavidKoontz I updated it with the basic component. But, even using the generate statement with it, I do not understand how to read only a specific output, as I would do with an array.

Comment: Was hoping you'd show  the arrays it would hook up to (only one shown - data), and their relationship does each cell have independent controls (set, calc)? Still too vague. Your entity incomplete, data has no subtype constraint. Generate loop based on how many cells fit in array.  Can make a multidimensional array type, would need to aggregate to it with type conversion, used to index which cell, or just offset arithmetic (elaboration time) based on generate loop constant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you weren't forthcoming with some parameters of how you were connecting these cells I made the assumption that each of the cells had it's own set and calc bits:

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;

entity cell is
    port (
        reset_n:    in  std_logic;
        clk_n:      in  std_logic;
        set:        in  std_logic;
        calc:       in  std_logic;
        data:       out std_logic_vector(1 downto 0)
    );
end entity;

architecture arch of cell is
    signal my_reg: std_logic_vector(1 downto 0);
begin
    data <= my_reg;
main: 
    process (clk_n, reset_n)
    begin
        if reset_n = '0' then
            my_reg <= "00";
        elsif clk_n'event and clk_n = '0' then -- falling_edge(clk_n)
            if set = '1' then
                my_reg <= "01";
            elsif calc = '1' and my_reg = "01" then
                my_reg <= "11";
            else
                my_reg <= "00";
            end if;
        end if;
    end process;
end architecture;

library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;

entity bunch is 
generic ( NUMBER_CELLS:     natural := 8);
    port (
    reset_n:    in  std_logic;
    clk_n:      in  std_logic;
    set:        in  std_logic_vector (NUMBER_CELLS - 1 downto 0);
    calc:       in  std_logic_vector (NUMBER_CELLS - 1 downto 0);
    data:       out std_logic_vector (NUMBER_CELLS * 2 - 1 downto 0)
    );
end entity;

architecture foo of bunch is 
    component cell is
        port (
            reset_n:    in  std_logic;
            clk_n:      in  std_logic;
            set:        in  std_logic;
            calc:       in  std_logic;
            data:       out std_logic_vector (1 downto 0)
        );
    end component;   
begin

GEN:
    for i in set'range generate
    CELLX:
        cell
            port map (
                reset_n => reset_n,
                clk_n => clk_n,
                set => set(i),
                calc => calc(i),
                data => data (i * 2 + 1 downto i * 2)
            );
    end generate;
end architecture;

library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;

entity bunch_tb is 
    constant NUMBER_CELLS:  natural := 8;
end entity;

architecture test of bunch_tb is
    constant CLK_PERIOD:    Time := 40 ns;
    signal reset_n:     std_logic := '1';
    signal clk_n:       std_logic := '1';
    signal set:         std_logic_vector(NUMBER_CELLS - 1 downto 0) 
                            := (others => '0');
    signal calc:        std_logic_vector(NUMBER_CELLS - 1 downto 0) 
                            := (others => '0');
    signal data:        std_logic_vector (NUMBER_CELLS * 2 - 1 downto 0);

begin
NOTCLK:
    process
    begin
        wait for CLK_PERIOD/2;
        clk_n <= not clk_n;
        if Now > 1400 ns then
            wait;
        end if;
    end process;

DUT:
    entity work.bunch 
        generic map (NUMBER_CELLS)
        port map (
            reset_n => reset_n,
            clk_n => clk_n,
            set => set,
            calc => calc,
            data => data
        );
STIMULUS:
    process
        variable bit: std_logic := '1';
    begin
        if Now = 0 ns then
            reset_n <= '0';
            wait for CLK_PERIOD;
        end if;
        if Now > 700 ns then
            bit := '0';
        end if;
        reset_n <= '1';
        set <= bit & set (NUMBER_CELLS - 1 downto 1); -- shift in '1','0'
        wait for CLK_PERIOD;
        calc <= bit & calc (NUMBER_CELLS -1 downto 1); -- shift in '1', '0'
        wait for CLK_PERIOD;
        if Now > 1440 ns then
            wait;
        end if;
    end process;    
end architecture;
```

As you might notice is changed the name of clk and reset to indicate the polarity, taken from your incomplete cell definition.

And this gives:

[image: bunch_tb.png]
*(clickable)*

If you had been a bit more specific I could have tailored the interfaces to match your expectations.

What this shows is how to hook up the different bus sizes for set, calc and data in a for generate loop.

This was done with ghdl-0.31 on OS X 10.9.5 with gtkwave 3.3.64.

> ghdl -a cell.vhdl
>   ghdl -e bunch_tb
>   ghdl -r bunch_tb --wave=bunch_tb.ghw

(And setting up the signals display in gtkwave).

Notice the tests for simulation time (Now) for stopping input stimulus in the testbench.

Comment: First of all thanks, now I can understand better how to use the generate statement. Where I was confused was that my idea was to access directly the my_reg signal, but your example shows how to do it correctly. very interesting also how you stop the simulation time, I always have forced ghdl to stop with the option --stop-time=XXXns.